# Как удалить определенный текст?

Tags: c

Есть текстовый файл, хочу чтоб из него удалились все предложение которые заканчиваются на восклицательный знак
я сделал только то что он удаляет сам знак, как сделать чтоб удалил предложение?

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c = 0;
    const unsigned char discard = '!';
    const char *file_name = "ex1.txt";
    FILE *input_file = NULL, *output_file = NULL;

    if (!(input_file = fopen(file_name,"r")) || !(output_file = fopen("ex2.txt","w")))
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"error handling"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(input_file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c != discard)
        {
            fputc(c,output_file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Определите четко что такое предложение.

Comment: Можно сохранять индекс начала предложения, и если в конце стоит восклицательный знак, затирать все от начала предложения до восклицательного знака.